# Java - How to make .jar file use external .txt file?

Tags: java

I have file "recipients.txt" that contains as you might have guessed list of recipients. I will need to update it from time to time, therefore I was planning on having it in the same directory as the .jar file I exported in order to do so.

At the moment i have it in the "bin" directory of my project in my eclipse workspace. I load the file into variable using FileReader.

When I tried exporting it as "runnable jar file" i could not access it. I've put an option there to show a JOptionPane with the path that the application was looking in, and it is weird.

The pane tells me that it was looking for file "\Desktop\JarFile.jarrecipients.txt".

Yes, that is correct, one "\" is missing.

So what am I doing wrong and how do I do this right?
I am pretty sure I am doing it all wrong, in which case how would I do it right? How could I have a file that I can keep up to date on a regular basis?
And how would I export it all to make it work?

The code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class DeliveryPackage {
public String recipientList="No Recipients";
public String recipientFileName = "recipients.txt";
public String recipientFilePath = DeliveryPackage.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString().replace("file:/","").replace("/", "\\") + recipientFileName;
public File recipientFile = new File(recipientFilePath);
public String fileNotFoundMessage = "File not found";
private String messageContents = "";
private String messageSubject = "";

public void setMessageSubject(String subject) {
    messageSubject = subject;
}

public String getMessageSubject() {
    return messageSubject;
}

public void setMessageContents(String message) {
    messageContents = message;
}

public String getMessageContents() {
    return messageContents;
}

public DeliveryPackage() {
    loadRecipients();
}

public String getRecipients(){
    return recipientList;
}

public String getRecipientFileName() {
    return recipientFileName;
}

public File getRecipientFile(String recipientFilePath) {
    File recipFile = new File(recipientFilePath);
    return recipFile;
}

public String getFileNotFoundMessage() {
    return "File not found";
}

public void loadRecipients() {

    if(recipientFile.exists() && !recipientFile.isDirectory()) { 
        String recipient;
        recipientList = "";
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(recipientFile);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while((recipient = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (recipient.trim().length() > 0) {
                    if (recipientList == "") {
                        recipientList = recipient;
                    } else {
                        recipientList = recipientList + "," + recipient;
                    }
                }
            }   
            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }       
    } else {
        recipientList = getFileNotFoundMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please provide the code where you read (or write) the file

Comment: @reporter Sorry, missed it. Updated now

Comment: @NielsNet Updated, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

As you can read here: [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320542/9356258)

This line returns the path of your jar file. Including the jars name.

```
DeliveryPackage.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString()
```

You should remove that. The question I mentioned shows how to do it.

Comment: he said that the pane gives him "\Desktop\JarFile.jarrecipients.txt". i think he only needs a slash

Comment: You can see that there is JarFile.jar in the path. That is the name of his jar file. Adding a slash wouldn't help.

Comment: well here is a link for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: @ElhoussineZennati that ia the link I used in my answer...

Comment: sorry man , i didn't check it , my bad

Comment: Why does it work in Eclipse and not when exported?
Using the link you gave me I am getting "/C:/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/project1/bin/", using what I already have gives me "C:\Users\username\eclipse-workspace\project1\bin\" so I have no idea whether it actually helps me

Comment: Alright, in the end I ended up checking if the path had ".jar" in it, and then I used lasIndexOf to manipulate the path to work.

Comment: @GohanCZ thw difference should be that it works both in eclipse and as jar.

Comment: @NielsNet I tried it, unfortunately it did not work. Therefore I had to do with a workaround.